# Spring boot Kafka stream listener same message consumed multiple times by seperate PODs/Consumers in the same consumer group

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Using Kafka and Spring boot kafka stream listener in my application. The configurations are:
160 partitions and the HPA is set to 6-40 so under peak load the pods scale to 40. The problem is that a single message on a single offset is getting consumed multiple times, sometimes as many as 15 times which is causing bottlenecks on DB and other problems at times.

```
log.info("Acknowledging message offset : {} for correlation ID {} time taken {} groupId {}", offset, message.getPayload().getCorrelationId(), (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime), groupId);
```

the same correlation id and same offset is being committed by multiple pods. I also printed the group ID so as to ensure all the pods are in same consumer group few of the logs are as below:

```
03-10-2020 15:39:23.966 [35m[KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='topic-input', partitions=0, dlqName='null'}.container-4-C-1][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m c.c.g.m.m.c.MessageConsumerImpl.processCreateWorkflow - Acknowledging message offset : 118347 for correlation ID f5979128-f69c-4b32-b510-6972ef1cadff time taken 2994 groupId topic
```

==========

```
03-10-2020 15:39:23.947 [35m[KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='topic-input', partitions=0, dlqName='null'}.container-5-C-1][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m c.c.g.m.m.c.MessageConsumerImpl.processCreateWorkflow - Acknowledging message offset : 119696 for correlation ID f5979128-f69c-4b32-b510-6972ef1cadff time taken 1434 groupId topic
```

The Pod id for those 2 logs are :   5f812fe2-38d4-430e-a395-943d77747b3a
and 194786f6-83df-4288-959c-7fcfb42de45a respectively.(they are different)

Another strange thing is both of them consuming messages from the same partition i.e. partition 0 none of the logs for any other partitions are printed though when we try to see we do see messages in other partitions.
Below are the configs for spring boot kafka stream listener:

```
stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: brkr:9092
          zkNodes: zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181
          autoCreateTopics: false
          # retry configs
          producerProperties:
            key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            value.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
            retries: 3
            max.in.flight.requests.per.connection: 1
            retry.backoff.ms: 9000
            request.timeout.ms: 400000
            delivery.timeout.ms: 450000
          applicationId: ng-member-service
          consumerProperties:
            key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
            #max.poll.records: 100
            auto.offset.reset: earliest
            session.timeout.ms: 300000
            request.timeout.ms: 400000
            allow.auto.create.topics: false
            heartbeat.interval.ms: 80000
        default:
          consumer:
            autoCommitOffset: false
          producer:
            messageKeyExpression: payload.entityId
        bindings:
          topic-input:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                max.poll.records: 350
      default:
        consumer:
          partitioned: true
          concurrency: 4
        producer:
          partitionKeyExpression: payload.entityId
          #partitionCount: 4
      bindings:
        topic-input:
          destination: topic-input
          group: topic
          consumer:
            maxAttempts: 1
            partitioned: true
            concurrency: 12
```

Any help on above would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the commits timing out or consumers rebalancing too often? This could cause some snowball effect in the consumer group, causing the messages to be seen multiple times. If you could try to check those things in the logs would be helpful!

Comment: default:
          consumer:
            autoCommitOffset: false

Comment: I meant have you tried enabling autoCommitOffset: true

Comment: nope but how is that gonna help?